# Trying to read InfoPlist.strings file... getting the key (?)

Tags: ios, localization, nsbundle

As many people don't know, the way to localize an application name on iOS and OSX is to add an `InfoPlist.strings` file to the bundle and localize that file. People mix this file with the `Info.Plist` file. Localization is not done into the `Info.plist`, is done in the `InfoPlist.strings` file.

Said that, I have created this file with two keys: `CFBundleDisplayName` and `CFBundleName`, as I always do. This works wonderfully and you can define different names for your app in different localizations. This file works seamlessly. You have to do nothing, just add the file to the project and localize it.

`InfoPlist.strings` is a strings file like this:

```
"CFBundleDisplayName" = "My Localized App Name";
"CFBundleName" = "My Localized App Name";
```

For this project in particular I have also to read the value of `CFBundleDisplayName` at run time.

I have tried to use this code:

```
NSString *appName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] localizedStringForKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName" value:nil table:@"InfoPlist"];
```

to read the `CFBundleDisplayName` key but the value I get back is `CFBundleDisplayName`. In other words, I provide the key and receive the key back, not the value. I should receive `My Localized App Name`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did this exactly in Swift, and it works as expected.

```
let appname = NSBundle.mainBundle().localizedStringForKey("CFBundleDisplayName", value: nil, table: "InfoPlist")
```

but, if I delete de localisation string from the corresponding `InfoPlist.strings` file, it returns **"CFBundleDisplayName"**.

So, check that you are not missing something in your `.strings` files

> **After trying several possibilities..**

The BUG was **"A second copy of InfoPlist.strings inside the project"**

Comment: wow, that is very strange. My `strings` file are perfect but I do not get the value, I get the key!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: what about your app name below the icon in the springboard? It shows correctly?

Comment: You are right. NOPE. The name is not appearing correctly on the device! What? How can that be?

Comment: check what language is set in your device, maybe, if that language is not in your strings...

Comment: or maybe that specific language file indeed has an sneaky bug that has elude you so far.

Comment: No, the language is on the device. I have changed the device to that language and the application is localized on that language. The language is portuguese, my natural language and I have done this a thousand times... it always worked. And I have tried it in english right now and it is not working either...

Comment: found the problem. A second copy of InfoPlist.strings inside the project! THANKS!

Comment: Good! nice, it was really a weird bug.